# Install Wordpress in subdirectory as addon domain and remove install folder in url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, addon-domain

I have installed an addon domain and created a subdirectory in the public_html folder where I installed wordpress for the new site. Everything works fine except the I cannot remove the subfolder from the url. I presume chhanging the htaccess file in the addondomain is the problem.

wordpress address url http://addondomain.com/addondomain
site url http://addondomain.com

in index.php in the addondomain folder I changed

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

to

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/addondomain/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

my htaccess file in the addon directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /addondomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /addondomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The htaccess file in the main public_html directory (contains files of another domain)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

All I want is to remove the wordpress installation folder from the url, but I have a domain and subdomain and two wp installations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the root folder of the addon domain which was set to the root directoryy, not subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove /addondomain from the last rule in .htaccess file in the addon directory (RewriteBase stays as before).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /addondomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```